# Angular8: Nested Lazy loading not working

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading, angular-routing

I want to create nested lazy loading in 3 levels but my scenario only works for the 2 base level app.module.ts and pages.module.ts
I want to create the same scenario for persons.module.ts from pages.module.ts

my **app.module.ts** define and routing module like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,      
  ],
  exports: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    AppRouteGuard,
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

and in my **app-routing.module.ts** I define these routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'pages',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/pages.module').then(mod => mod.PagesModule),
    canActivate : [AppRouteGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'pages', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'pages' },
];

const config: ExtraOptions = {
  useHash: true,
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, config)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

and in my **pages.module.ts** I define a pages-routing.module.ts that have these codes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PagesComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: ECommerceComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'persons',
        loadChildren: () => import('./persons/persons.module').then(mod => mod.PersonsModule)
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'persons',
        pathMatch: 'full',
      },
      {
        path: '**',
        component: NotFoundComponent,
      }
    ]
  }];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class PagesRoutingModule {
}
```

everything is ok for these levels but when I define **persons-routing.module.ts** 
like this :

```
    const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'account-likes',
        component: LikesComponent
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'account-likes',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  }
    ]


    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule],
    })
    export class PersonRoutingModule {
    }
```

and my temlplate like this:

```
<div class="row ml-0">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-5 col-lg-2 p-0 person-sidebar">
    <nb-card size="small" class="mb-0">
           hello world
    </nb-card>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-7 col-lg-10 pl-0">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

my **persons.component.html** display nothing 
can you help me?

Comment: Any errors in browser's console?

Comment: @hrdkisback I don't get any error just not display anything in person.component.html

Answer (score 1):

> Check this Working Example [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nested-lazy-loaded-routing?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: I add the same code for that example but I don't know where is my code have problem

Comment: do u  still have problem

Comment: can you post you error log in console to ur questiion

Answer (score 0):

In your example  the issue is in the PersonRoutingModule as no component is defined in Routes arrays so need to update   the component in  PersonRoutingModule.ts

Comment: I add PersonComponent for path=' ' but already not display anything

Comment: I add PersonComponent for path=' ' but already not display anything

Comment: In module Component name is required